# Azure Billing for storage account

Tags: azure

Good Day.

I'm new to Azure cloud and trying to understand different services.

We have FileShare storage account which is mounted on the VMs that are created. Will Azure defender be enabled by default for Storage accounts? Reason am asking is we are getting around 30-40% of the bill only for 'advanced threat protection'. Not sure if this is something related to azure defender or data transfer charges. If it is Azure defender then do we really need this as we don't have this charge for other storage account (general purpose v2).

Attached the description that is present in the billing, and don't have any other information to understand more.

[image]

Any inputs/suggestions would be very helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this page you have the [optional Advanced Threat Protection for Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/azure-defender-storage-configure?tabs=azure-security-center) enabled via Security Center. [Pricing can be found here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/security-center/). This is an opt-in service which can be applied at the subscription level. I'd talk to your subscription owner or security team to determine if they'll allow you to turn it off.

Comment: Thanks @Josh, but any idea what 'Standard transactions' in the billing description mean? Trying to understand more on this whether is it something related to transactions or is it something else. Thanks

Comment: This page has the per transaction price - 2cents per 10k transactions. Transactions are typically tied to standard API calls.  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/azure-defender/

Comment: Thanks Josh for the reply. I see that the number of transactions on the FileShare storage account is way too high. We are using this to mount to the VMs, and also write the logs. Not sure if the transaction count will be down if write it to blob storage instead of Fileshare. Think it still would be the same. Thanks again

Comment: @Josh I am also confused about transactions, but for blob storage. Are 10k transactions equal to the 10k uploaded blobs? I can't find a specific explanation, so can you answer me, is 10k transactions == 10k blobs?